# How to get access to the linear expression of a GuRoBi constraint

Tags: c++, gurobi

I am trying to add variables to an already created constraint and I am struggling a bit with the documentation. I initially create an empty constraint like this:

```
std::vector<GRBConstr> path_cons(k);

for (auto k = 0; k < num_commodities; ++k)
{
    GRBLinExpr expr = 0;

    name.str(""); 
    name << "path_" << k;

    path_cons[k] = model.addConstr(expr == 1.0, name.str().c_str());
}
```

At some point of times later, I want to add variables to these k constraints.

something like this.

```
for (...)
   if (index == k)
      add xvar[k] with a coefficient of 1.0 to path_cons[k]
```

I am wondering if I can just create a new linear expression and add it to the constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Call GRBModel:chgCoeff() to set the coefficients:

```
for (...)
   if (index == k)
      model.setCoeff(path_cons[k], xvar[k], 1.0);
```